# azure-cosmosdb DocumentDB Migration tool errors

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am having trouble loading JSON or CSV data into Azure CosmosDB using the DocumentDB Data Migration tool.  I have tried both CSV and JSON and I get the ID and Label but none of the other properties associated with the document.

Example JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": "AB7FB330-5C81-E411-80CF-00155D011702",
    "name": "DeIdentified 1",
    "adopted": "No",
    "ageatscan": 63,
    "allergies": "Aspirin, Opiod",
    "ChildMedicalDisorders": null,
    "DateOfBirth": "1953-04-28T00:00:00Z",
    "Ethnicity": "Caucasian",
    "EyeDominance": null,
    "Gender": "Female",
    "HandDominance": "Right",
    "Height": "5ft6",
    "HighestEducation": "Bachelor's Degree",
    "MilitaryHistory": "No",
    "MilitaryStatus": "None",
    "NeuroPsychTestingDone": "No",
    "PatientClassification": "Neuorpsychy Patient",
    "ReferringPhyID": null,
    "ReferringPhysicianName": null,
    "Weight": 130,
    "ResidenceState": "CO",
    "label": "Patient"
  },
  {
    "id": "72D52694-6181-E411-80CF-00155D011702",
    "name": "DeIdentified 2",
    "adopted": "No",
    "ageatscan": 24,
    "allergies": null,
    "ChildMedicalDisorders": null,
    "DateOfBirth": "1990-09-27T00:00:00Z",
    "Ethnicity": null,
    "EyeDominance": null,
    "Gender": "Female",
    "HandDominance": null,
    "Height": null,
    "HighestEducation": null,
    "MilitaryHistory": "No",
    "MilitaryStatus": null,
    "NeuroPsychTestingDone": "No",
    "PatientClassification": "Neuorpsychy Patient",
    "ReferringPhyID": null,
    "ReferringPhysicianName": null,
    "Weight": 105,
    "ResidenceState": "CO",
    "label": "Patient"
  },
.
.
.
```

Comment: Hi, any updates? If you adopt my answer, you could mark it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I tried import your documents and everything works fine. I suggest you checking the format of your `json` file or the error log file.

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: From your reputation I assume you are aware, that this is more suitable as a comment instead of an answer.